# Android unit test generated jacoco coverage doesn’t contain original code coverage report

Tags: android, junit, instrumentation

I have written the unit test codes and the Android.bp build file with “instrumentation_for” attribute targeting the indicated app to test, after I use the command “EMMA_INSTRUMENT=true EMMA_INSTRUMENT_STATIC=true UNSAFE_DISABLE_HIDDENAPI_FLAGS=true make [unittest app]” and use adb to run the coverage test command, it only generates coverage report for test code classes, which are all 99-100%, but no report for original codes, which I am supposed to get.

Can anyone please help to answer this question?

I run the test with adb, but reports only for test code classes are generated